# R ggplot connecting one point on a map with multiple points on the same map

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to connect one location on the map of the US with multiple locations on the map of the US.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flights13)
```

First, I am selecting all flights from Newark airport (EWR) on January 1, 2013 and grabbing the geographic coordinates for the destinations (if available in the tibble *airports* - and add EWR's location on top):

```
ewr <- flights %>% 
         filter(year== 2013, month== 1, day== 1, origin== "EWR") %>%  
         select(dest) %>% 
         distinct(dest) %>% 
         arrange(dest)

# Join it with airports database, add column "origin" filled with EWR:
mydest <- ewr %>% 
            left_join(select(airports, faa, lat, lon), 
                      by = c("dest" = "faa")) %>%
            filter(!is.na(lat)) %>% 
            select(lat, lon)
mydest

# Grab EWR coords:
ewrcoords <- airports %>% 
               filter(faa == "EWR") %>% 
               select(lat, lon)
ewrcoords
mydest <- rbind(ewrcoords, mydest)
```

Then, I want to connect the EWR (Newark) location with all the destination locations. I tried to do it using a loop, but it's not working inside `ggplot`:

```
mydest %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat)) +
  borders("state") +
  geom_point() +
  coord_quickmap() %>%
  for(i in 2:nrow(mydest)) {
    geom_line(data = mydest[c(1,i),], aes(lon, lat), 
              color = "black", size = 1)
  }
```

Is it possible to do it without a loop? Or how could I make the loop work?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Probably something like: `coord_quickmap() +
  lapply(2:nrow(mydest), function(i) {
    geom_line(data = mydest[c(1,i),] , aes(lon, lat), 
              color = "black", size = 1)
  })`. But you could also do it with a single call to `geom_segment` if you create a data frame with lat and and lon for EWR as one pair of columns (for x and y) and lat and lon for other airports as another pair of columns (for xend and yend).

Comment: Thank you so much! geom_segment was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
colnames(ewrcoords) = c("EWRlat", "EWRlon")
mydest <- cbind(ewrcoords, mydest)

mydest %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat)) +
  borders("state") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(y=EWRlat, x=EWRlon, xend=lon, yend=lat))+
  coord_quickmap()
```

EDIT: sorry did not see it was already in the comment by eipi10.

Comment: Thank you so much! geom_segment was exactly what I was looking for!