# Connecting all dots on a ggplot2 map to a single point [in R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I have finally managed to make a map which includes points for a range of long,lat coordinates.

I have used the following code to make the map

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=wmap_laea_df, aes(long,lat,group=group), fill="white")+
  geom_path(data=countries_laea_df, aes(long,lat, group=group), color="light grey",
        size=0.1) +
  geom_point(data=loc_laea_df, aes(V1, V2, group=NULL,fill=NULL,size=V3),
         color="black",alpha=I(6/10)) +
  scale_size(range=c(1,2.5), guide = "legend",labs(size="Count")) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c((xmin-buff),(xmax+buff)), ylim = c((ymin-buff),(ymax+buff))) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)+
  theme_opts
```

This produces the following plot

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am now trying to connect the dots, to a single point (the Northern most point in the Scotland). The only thing I could think of was to use the following line:

```
 geom_line(data=loc_laea_df, aes(x=V1, y=V2), color="black", size=1)
```

This produces the following:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This however is not the outcome I had hoped for, but feel I am on the way. 
Could anyone point me in the direction of how to do that?

**EDIT:**

For anyone seeing this later, I found a great solution described here:

[R ggplot connecting one point on a map with multiple points on the same map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158896/r-ggplot-connecting-one-point-on-a-map-with-multiple-points-on-the-same-map#comment79280896_46158896)

Comment: You'll need to use `geom_path`. But we can't suggest a solution without a sample of your data.

Comment: Thanks for reposnding. I have made a data dump below

Comment: If I run your data dump your code still doesn't work for me. I'm missing `wmap_laea_df`.. and more

Comment: I tried giving some more info/code. Hope this helps!